# How to validate HTML Reports using Watir

Tags: watir

We are trying to validate the **HTML** reports generated by our application. We have planned the below approach to do this

1. Capture that data related to the report from application
2. Generate the report
3. Identify the report’s elements and compare the data captured from application against the data/elements in report.

We started with identification of elements of the report and found that using `'Developers tool'` we are able get some of the object properties where the Object ID is missing from these properties.
Can anyone please let us know the possibility of capturing the report elements and comparing them with the application data.

Comment: What exactly is the problem?

Comment: Hi Flipin,
I would like to know
1) the possiblity of capturing application (page data) into an array variable
2) the possiblity of capturing/identifying the elements dispalyed in HTML Report to compare the application data against the report to valdate the report.

Reagards,
Veera.

Comment: I still do not understand what you are trying to do. Show us examples. HTML, screenshots, code...

Comment: I am having problem while captuirng data from HTML Report. I have used the method " relationship_in_report = get_element_text(popup, :td, :class, 'A06df9158c527411db1b8fef473271b9a12896')" which is giving me the error "Unable to Return text in td class='A06df9158c527411db1b8fef473271b9a12896': 'Unable to locate element, using :class, "A06df9158c527411db1b8fef473271b9a12896" "

Comment: I think i should use table methods to capture the data from this reoport but I am not sure which method to use. I am unable to attach screen shot of the HTML report source here

Comment: To heck with a screenshot, EDIT your question and embed some of the HTML and format it as 'code'  Without people being able to see the HTML you are trying to work with, and a better idea of what you are trying to do, you're not going to get much in the way of answers since you are basically saying "I'm uh trying to do this thing, with this stuff, and it's not working and I need help"

Comment: Hi, the report we are generating from our web application is an SSRS Report and below is some portion of the source code from which i want to capture the value "POC_Reports_test" class="Abcc5464c1acc4c48b277f0e6d02ce75e12824">:</TD></TR></TABLE></TD><TD></TD><TD COLSPAN="2"><TABLE CELLSPACING="0" CELLPADDING="0" LANG="en-US" style=""><TR><TD style="WIDTH:46.96mm;min-width:46.96mm;HEIGHT:4.76mm;" class="Abcc5464c1acc4c48b277f0e6d02ce75e12896">POC_Reports_test</TD></TR></TABLE>. Can you please let me know the possibilty of capturing the values from this report using Watir.

Answer (score 1):

Frankly if you are just trying to parse HTML, and not trying to drive a browser, you'd probably be better off using something like Nokogiri, or another library aimed specifically at parsing HTML  See https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/html_parsing for a selection of such tools

Watir is 'Web Application Testing In Ruby" it is designed to drive web-browsers, in order to test websites and webapps.  Validation that portions of the HTML are as expected is a part of that, but not the core functionality of Watir.

For what you are trying to do, if I understand you right, you could use watir to do that, in somewhat the same way you can use excel for word processing and page layout, which is to say it can be done, but may not be the most preferred tool or easiest way to go about it.